# Parse retrieving data matching several different values

Tags: android, cloud

I'm retrieving Objects in parse but it always goes to ParseException

Here's my code :

```
public void setItemListData(Context context, String className, 
            String[] value, String colName) {
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery(className);
        query.whereContainsAll("Store",Arrays.asList (value));
        query.whereEqualTo("Store","Asus");
        dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            List<ParseObject> dataHolder = query.find();
            for(int counter =0;counter<dataHolder.size();counter++){
                String datas = dataHolder.get(counter).getString(colName);
                dataList.add(datas);    
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"No Internet Connection",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you use `e.printStackTrace()` what are the exceptions?

Comment: wait i didn't print it. I'll check and update you

Comment: e.printStackTrace() = @all works on array fields

Answer (score 1):

```
Change query.whereContainsAll("Store",Arrays.asList (value));
```

to

```
query.whereContainedIn("Store",Arrays.asList (value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Find **multiple** values in **single** query:

```
private List<ParseObject> todos;
```

Code for find multiple values:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Your_Class_Name");
String[] names = {"Hiren", "Dhruv", "Pratik", "Miral", "Kirit"};
   query.whereContainedIn("Your_Column_Name_Means_Key", Arrays.asList(names));
    try {
         todos = query.find();
         Log.i("No Of Record Found",todos.size()+"");
        }catch (ParseException e) {
         e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

You have to **pass** your **Class Name** and **Your Column Name**.

**Done**